# iOS 5 UIAlertView customisation

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

I am adding UIButton to UIAlertView as below

[image: iOS 5 app]

it is fine with iOS 6 and below now in iOS 7 it comes like this

[image: iOS 5 app in iOS 7 device]

Please let us know the way to resolve this issue.

Comment: I don't think your images came through correctly, but you probably need to post your code for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: explain your query properly. then only will get any help.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated images/screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add any view as a sub view in alert view as per the IOS 7 standard. please refer apple document. (UIAlert view customization not possible in IOS 7)

Please refer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1

Comment: We have already tried to add UITextField which is working fine but UIButton is not working as expected.

Comment: @Umang: You got lucky with the text field. ("Lucky" might not be the right word, considering your app is going to get rejected for doing it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1)

But this is wrong approach , you can see this on same [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView-SW1)

`Alertview` should only use to show below details

- Be immediately informed of critical information
- Make a decision about a course of action

For above task you should use `pickerview` or `tableview` depends on the requirement.