# Cant click on button in UIAlertView after adding UIImageview to subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uialertview, addsubview

The Ok button is not working.
I know it happened because I added backgroundImageView.
How can i make it work?

This is my code:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clock"]];

backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 200);

backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
backgroundImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[alert addSubview:backgroundImageView];

[alert sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView];

[alert show];
```

Comment: Try this https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

Comment: The same code works for me. Maybe some different thing overlaps your alertView like tapGestureRecognizer or another subview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19028950/1545180 refer this.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Apple will not allow you to add subviews or modify the view hierarchy. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html for:

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

And see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIAlertView for:

> **Appearance of Alert Views**
>
> You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

Going against these will get your App rejected in the Apple Review process - so I would go back and look at your design of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will not allow you to add subviews to `UIAlertView`. Subclassing `UIAlertView` is not an option, this class is not intended to be subclassed and doing so might be a reason of app rejection.

You can use a library from [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UIalertview) for custom `UIAlertView`

Answer (score 1):

Don't add subviews to `UIAlertView`, it is not supported functionality. If you need to create custom views, find a 3rd parts alert view solution which supports what you need and use that instead.

Comment: just simple correction from iOS 7 onwards we can't customize standard alert view.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre, it was never supported functionality and it should never have been done - this isn't new to iOS7, it just doesn't work at all in iOS7.

Comment: @Wain whilst I do agree that it shouldn't have been allowed and it can't be done at all now. Apple sometimes would allow an app to slip through the process I have an old app that did this. But now this certainly will not happen.

Comment: @Popeye, indeed, I know of several that use this loophole. From Apples point of view it was hard to review as there was a 3rd party implementation for iOS6 that looks basically identical to the built in version.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not recommend adding subviews to `UIAlertView` You will have to create your own alert view.